# Best way to generate list of random integers with replacement

Tags: python, random, integer

I am able to generate a list of random integers with replacement using a for loop, but it seems verbose and there must be a more elegant way of doing this with either pure python or using `random` without a loop.  Are there more optimal solutions that would produce the outcome `rand_list` below without appending on every loop?

```
import random

rand_list = [] 

for x in range(100):

    r = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5])
    rand_list.append(r)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to use the function `choices` from the random package, you were just missing the "s"! Also, you would need to add the `k` parameter to account for how many values do you want to sample:

```
values = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(random.choices(values,k=10))
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4]
```

In your example, you would need to fix k to 100.

Comment: This is probably the simplest/most obvious answer

Comment: And gets the job done, I believe this is what OP was needing.

Answer (score 1):

[`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) does exactly what you need:

```
from random import choices

rand_list = choices(range(1, 6), k=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `random.choices`:

```
from random import choices

rand_list = choices(range(1,6),k=100)
```

Here `k` is the number of the random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)

```py
rand_list = [(random.randrange(5) + 1) for x in range(100)]
```

If you have a heavier function (perhaps a complex hash or return extremely large values), you can delay the creation of values by using a generator. This saves memory and allows processing to occur before the entire list has been created. You could break after a count of values, or [iterate over a slice of it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36106880/4541045) if only a certain number are needed (rather than a continuous process).

```py
import itertools
import random

def gen():
    while True:
        yield random.randrange(5) + 1

max_iterations = 100

for value in itertools.islice(gen(), max_iterations):
    do_some_opertation(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(list(random.choices([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], k=100)))
```