# How to iterate over a list of dict to an nth index?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that I want to iterate over, but I only want to iterate up until a specific index rather that the entirety of the list.

My code:

```
new_hero_list = []
for hero in hero_data:
        dict = {key: value for key, value in hero.items() if key in keys}
        # some stuff ...
        new_hero_list.append(dict)
```

The list `hero_data` contains 100+ dictionaries, but in most cases I only want to iterate over the first `nth` indexes, such as 3. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Comment: `for hero in hero_data[:n]`?

Comment: You need to use the `range()` function in your loop.

Comment: @gold_cy Thanks, that is what I was looking for. I was considering a counter after posting, but your answer is much cleaner.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim ``enumerate`` is more pythonic than ``range`` - unless you have to support Python 2.2 or older

Comment: @MikeScotty I'd say depends on how it's used. Would you somehow use `enumerate` instead of `range` [here](https://tio.run/##VYzBCoMwEETv@xV7MwHpxUsR/JJSwrZZNSCbZQ0U@/Op2pNzfG9mdCtzlu6uVuvMlkOkQjhgQ6935LEBEP6E0yxpLbt5PGHMhqHFg2IS/CZ1RjKx6/yfni@@B9xz2d9IlSW6A3gAtSTFXRq@1h8)?

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim wrapping it in ``zip`` is actually a nice idea and saves you the ``if(...): break`` inside the loop. When you suggested to use ``range`` I thought you meant it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/522569/4349415) where you then access the item by index and you'd still have to use an ``if(...): break`` to exit the loop.

Comment: I found a dupe that uses zip+range: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106712/how-can-i-limit-iterations-of-a-loop-in-python

Comment: @MikeScotty I am actually doing something similar in another screen right now that requires me to compare the list of dicts to another list and I'm working on a zip with range solution. I didn't expand on the idea because I'm still working on it.

Answer (score 1):

one way you can use is enmerator to track the count of the iteration and you can break the for loop when your nth iteration is met

```
new_hero_list = []
for index, (key, value) in enumerate(hero_data.items()):
    dict = {key: value for key, value in hero.items() if key in keys}
    # some stuff ...
    new_hero_list.append(dict)
    if index == n:
      break
```