# How to print first 5 keys and values from dictionary in Python for below code?

Tags: python

I want to print first 5 keys and values from my dictionary but I can't do that. I'm trying with while loop in different position but it's not working for me.
Please help me how can I do that.

**Code:**

```
def table_dict(dictionary):
    if isinstance(dictionary, str):
        return '<td>'+dictionary+'</td>'
    s = ['<!-- wp:table --><figure class="wp-block-table"><table><tbody>']
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        s.append('<tr><td>%s</td>' % key)
        # s.append('<tr><td>'+key+'</td>')
        s.append('<td>%s</td>' % value)
        s.append('</tr>')
    s.append('</tbody></table></figure><!-- /wp:table -->')
    return ''.join(s)

dictionary = {"name" : "John", "age" : 35, "height" : 65, "country:": "US", "weight": "50 KG", "nationality": "N/A"}
print(table_dict(dictionary))
```

Comment: what do you mean by row in the python Dict

Comment: a dict has no row and no order. You need to specify which keys you want to print one by one in the order you wish.

Comment: Could you add in your question: what is your error message, and what is the exact expected output ?

Comment: As it is, it prints content of that dictionary in a table - what's your objective?

Comment: @TamilSelvan this code is for a wp table that's why I said to row.

Comment: I want to print first 5 keys and values according to my function.

Comment: @Malo I am trying to get the first five keys and values. Please check my answer comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I limit iterations of a loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36106712/6045800)

Answer (score 0):

You have clearly the problem that order is not guaranteed in `dict` - you could solve that using an `ordereddict`.

Under that scenario, to print the first n *lines* (maybe it is better to say *entries*), you could modify your code as follows:

```
def table_dict(dictionary, max_entries = 5):
    if isinstance(dictionary, str):
        return '<td>'+dictionary+'</td>'
    s = ['<!-- wp:table --><figure class="wp-block-table"><table><tbody>']
    for n, [key, value] in enumerate(dictionary.items()):
        if n == max_entries:
            break
        s.append('<tr><td>%s</td>' % key)
        # s.append('<tr><td>'+key+'</td>')
        s.append('<td>%s</td>' % value)
        s.append('</tr>')
    s.append('</tbody></table></figure><!-- /wp:table -->')
    return ''.join(s)
```

Using this logic, if a dictionary has more than `max_entries` element, the output will be truncated to the first `max_entries`.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary does not contain any rows. It contains of keys and values.

If you want to print out the keys separately which you might refer as rows you have to do:

```
dictionary.pop("nationality")
for key, value in dictionary.items()
    print(key, ':', value)
```

This is how I understand your problem, if not please consider redescribing it.